# How to sketch the graph of $f(x,y)=y/x$ by using level curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

I came across this problem, to sketch the graph of $f(x,y) = y/x$ using level curves.
I have realized that the level curves of the function are of the form $y=kx$.
But I don't really know how to draw it on the $\mathbb{R}^3$ space.
I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Take a side view of hyperbolic  paraboloid surface $y= x z$. In Physics analogy we have Boyle's Law $ xy= const$ and two Charles laws  $ x/z= const, y/z= const$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y) = z = y/x$. So you're saying the intersection with the plane $z =k$ is the line $y=kx$.

Does this help?